# How important is it to the man in the following question?

Tags: meaning

だって大事なんだよ… それくらい、お前のことが大切なんだってば

I would translate it like:
You are important... 
That is how much you mean to me

The story goes like this (context); One man punches his best friend (who he loved) because that friend wanted to have his wife. After doing that he says that sentence to his wife and they have a sweet love moment.

How important is it to the man in the following question? Does it imply the man considers his relationship with his wife is more important than his friend? If there's a subtlety I might have missed in that regard please tell me.

I understand what the sentence means, I'm asking about the emphasis it was said with in japanese.

Comment: This is hard to answer. He says his wife is as important as **それ/that**, but I don't get what それ exactly refers to from the context you provided. Maybe his wife said something before this? What was that?

Comment: @naruto The 2 previous sentences from the man were: マイケルを、壊しちゃった(I broke Michael) and あいつ、あたしのせいであんなに傷ついてた。なのに、心の中はなにも変わってなかった (he got so broken because of me, yet nothing changed in my heart). After that he says だって大事なんだよ… それくらい、お前のことが大切なんだってば His wife doesn't talk, she just hugs him. マイケルを、壊しちゃった(I broke Michael) was the first thing he said, there's no more conversation prior to that, just him punching him and destroying his hopes because he won't give up on his wife (even for his best friend).

Comment: Wait, did the man really say "あたし"? That's a fairly feminine first-person pronoun.

Comment: @naruto Sorry, I've been away for 2 days. My mistake, he says あいつ、俺のせいであんなに傷ついてた。心の中はなにも変わってなかった。Both males are best friends. My guess is that それ would mean that his wife is "that important". Something like "you are that important to me". And それ would refer to him cutting his ties with his best friend and breaking him for his wife. Something like "That is how much you mean to me". Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> だって大事なんだよ… それくらい、お前のことが大切なんだってば

妻｛つま｝は、その友達｛ともだち｝が夫｛おっと｝にとってとても大切｛たいせつ｝な友達｛ともだち｝だと知｛し｝っているので、「どうしてあなたがあんなに好｛す｝きな友達｛ともだち｝を殴｛なぐ｝ったの」と言｛い｝ったか、または、言｛い｝うと同｛おな｝じくらい効果｛こうか｝がある表情｛ひょうじょう｝か態度｛たいど｝を夫｛おっと｝に示｛しめ｝したのだと思｛おも｝います。

Because the wife knows that the friend of her husband is very important for him, she might have said to him, "why did you hit the friend whom you like best?", or she might have shown a facial expression or a manner to him which had an effect almost as same as what she might have said.

夫｛おっと｝が妻｛つま｝に言｛い｝った「だって大事｛だいじ｝なんだよ… それくらい ＝ だってそれくらい大事｛だいじ｝なんだよ。」の中｛なか｝の「それ」とは、「本当｛ほんとう｝なら殴｛なぐ｝ることなどとても考｛かんが｝えられない自分｛じぶん｝が、大好｛だいす｝きな友達｛ともだち｝を殴｛なぐ｝るという行為｛こうい｝に及｛およ｝んだ（＝及｛およ｝ばざるを得｛え｝なかった）こと」を指｛さ｝していると思｛おも｝います。

I think "それ" in the phrase "だって大事なんだよ… それくらい = だってそれくらい大事なんだよ" which he said to her pointed at the seriously big fact that he was not able to avoid hitting his best friend with whom the husband had such relationship that it can hardly assume that he hit the friend.

Comment: Can you please say the same in english? I'm afraid I might be missing some points otherwise.

Comment: Another thing. Did you read my comment to Naruto? What do you think after reading that?

Comment: @Mac Now I read the 2 previous sentences from the man in the comment to Naruto. I have a question. Who said 「あいつ、あたしのせいであんなに傷ついてた。なのに、心の中はなにも変わってなかった。」 ? If it is said by the husband it should be like 「あいつ、俺のせいであんなに傷ついてた。心の中はなにも変わってなかった。」

Comment: It wasn't a literal transcription. What's the difference? To me both mean the same

Comment: I checked it, it is as you say

Comment: @Mac >It wasn't a literal transcription. If so I have to re-consider your question, because the husband spoke in a woman-ish expression. And the phrase "who he loved" made me think the husband loved the boyfriend Michael, besides Michael loves his wife. So, the husband and Michael are both bisexual males. Now the situation is very complicated. I recommend you to
re-write the question with more precise description of the situation and with previous lines spoken by the husband.